# Jquery how to get each row's index which is created dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

currently if i delete a value in the middle without deleting it sequentially, the same item as the last one will be printed
(Example: If you create an item with values 1, 2, 3, and then delete item numbering 2 in the middle, next time you generate the item, value will be generated as 1, 3, 3 when the next item is created.)

here is JS code

```js
var idx = 0;
    /*  modal */
    $('.js-shopTransportAdd').click(function () {
        var addContainer = $(this).closest('.js-shopTransportAdd-container');
        var findInputLength = addContainer.find(".js-findLength").length;
        var count = findInputLength++

        var html =
                '<div class="c-modal-item row js-shopTransportDelete-target js-findLength">\n' +
            '<div class="col-5">\n' +
            '<div class="c-modal-info">\n' +
            '<label class="c-modal-info__ttl for="transport-area1">地域名</label>\n' +
            '<input class="c-input--text form-control" type="text" name="transportRegionWriteFormList[' + count + '].regionName" value="">' +
            '</div>\n' +
            '</div>\n' +
            '<div class="col-5">\n' +
            '<div class="c-modal-info">\n' +
            '<label class="c-modal-info__ttl" for="transport-area-fee1">費用</label>\n' +
            '<input class="c-input--text form-control" type="text" name="transportRegionWriteFormList[' + count + '].regionPrice" value="">' +
            '</div>\n' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-2">\n' +
            '<div class="c-modal-info">\n' +
            '<span class="c-input--minus js-shopTransportDelete"></span>\n' +
            '</div>\n' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>'
        addContainer.append(html)


        $('.js-shopTransportDelete').on('click', function () {
            var deleteContainer = $(this).closest('.js-shopTransportDelete-target');
            idx = deleteContainer.index();

            count = idx;
            deleteContainer.remove();

        });
    });
```

HTML

```html
                           <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <h2 class="c-modal-list__ttl">地域別配送料設定</h2>
                                    <div class="c-modal-list js-shopTransportAdd-container">
                                        <div class="c-modal-item ">
                                            <span class="c-input--plus js-shopTransportAdd"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

i have tried to find each index using index() as below but didnt worked

```js
idx= addContainer.find(".js-findLength").index();
```

could you please help me?

Comment: Create a global variable. After adding 1 item, increase the value of this global variable. It's quite easy, my friend.

Comment: uhmm sorry i tried counter as global varialble and other variable but didnt work ㅜㅜ